JsPDF Autotable, arabic text does not fill the whole cell
I'm trying to use arabic text in a table using JsPdf and Autotable but im having issues of formatting. Text doesn't align properly and doesn't fill the whole cell.
Here's the style i used for the cell:
{
  "content": arabicText,
   styles: {halign: "right", direction: 'rtl', lang: 'ar', cellWidth: 100,
   fontStyle: 'Amiri', fontSize: 9}
},

Here's how it looks:

